# How to access the data stored in HDD?

Tags: hdd

I removed the HDD from my broken labtop to take the data stored in.

This is the HDD:

[image]

I don''t know which cable I can use to connect it with my new laptop with USB port .

Could any one explain to me how can I do that?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Comment: USB to Sata adapter.

Comment: I bought one of these on Amazon for about $6 USD: http://kutyubazar.hu/103-3046-large/sata-ide-usb-atalakito-adapter-tapegyseggel-kabelekkel-kutyubazar-usb-003.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can buy a 2.5" USB HDD caddy. They're fairly cheap and easy to assemble! Something similar to this: [here](https://uk.eucomtech.eu/usb-30-uasp-25hdd-enclosure.phtmlhttps://uk.eucomtech.eu/usb-30-uasp-25hdd-enclosure.phtml?gclid=CjwKEAiArdG1BRCLvs_q-IObwxMSJACXbLtzw73ddgVExW5s8Kr2xYVdgyI3d46-nvVeXifvzmQxoRoCbqTw_wcB)

Comment: How he will connect it to a USB port?

Comment: The caddy has USB, you should know that.

Comment: [The one's I know](http://www.amazon.com/SATA-caddy-12-7mm-Universal-DVD-ROM/dp/B0056EW4A4) are just for fitting a HDD into a Optical drive place.

Comment: You can find one here http://uk.cellphonecases.com/Usb-2.0-Sata-2.5-Inch-Hard-Drive-Case-Silver.html?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=productads&gclid=CjwKEAiArdG1BRCLvs_q-IObwxMSJACXbLtz94iyuvli-DNm3UHc97FBlnf3CY-sno7CmTVRogI5SRoCeK3w_wcB#.VrSJmaCnzqA

Comment: Yeah, that's a regular usb to sata case. Also, the word "caddy" doesn't appear in that page. I think there's a naming issue here. But since this question seems off-topic anyway, it doesn't really matter.